# Loading a number of xml file into logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

i want to load a number of xml file into logstash in the same time, so what i should to add in my config file!.

Thanks guys for your support :)

this is my config file :

```
input {
 file {
  path => "D:/test*.xml",
  start_position => beginning
  sincedb_path => "NUL"
  codec => multiline {
  pattern => "<invoicing>|</invoicing>"
  negate => "true"
  what => "previous"
  auto_flush_interval => 1
  max_lines => 3000
  }

 }
}


filter {
  xml {
   source => "message"
   target => "message.parsed"
   store_xml => false
   force_array => false

  }

}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
elasticsearch {
  index => "tizer005"
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  document_type => "ChannelFiles"
 }
}
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i ve tried to add just one xml file but i have 100 other  waiting, there is any possibility to load the all in the same time @Mysterion

Comment: Could you share your config?

Comment: this is my config file in up @Mysterion

Comment: Are you sure your path setting is correct?

Comment: my path is path => "D:/test001.xml" but i replace is with path => "D:/test*.xml" hoping it will work

Comment: Path part looks okay, do you see any errors in logstash logs?

Comment: no because its sames weird